# Find the names of employees whose name has more than two ‘a’ in it and ends with ‘s’. ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm attempting to select from a table the names of employees whose name has two 'a' in it and end with s. Heres what I have so far
`select NAME from CLASS where NAME LIKE '%s'`

I know how to find names where they end with s but not sure how to search for names having atleast two 'a'.

Comment: You can combine your current attempt with one of the solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169471/how-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-an-oracle-varchar-value

Comment: thanks ended up using that and my solution was: ```select NAME from CLASS where NAME LIKE '%s' and REGEXP_COUNT(NAME, 'a') > 2;```

Comment: @cise Surely `'a.*a.*s$'` would so it, if you really want a regex? But Luke Winward's `like ''%a%a%a%s'` is simpler and faster.

Answer (score 3):

Am I missing something, or could you just not just write

```
select NAME from CLASS where LOWER(NAME) LIKE '%a%a%a%s'
```

?

This selects every name that has at least three (i.e. more than two) `a`s, and ends with an `s`.

Comment: To fit OP's need it would be more than two a's, so `%a%a%s`.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be

```
where regexp_count(name, 'a', 1, 'i') = 2
  and substr(lower(name), -1) = 's'
```

- number of `'a'` letters - starting at position `1`, performing case insensitive search (`'i'`) = 2
- the last character is `'s'`

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:
`select NAME from CLASS where NAME LIKE '%s' and REGEXP_COUNT(NAME, 'a') > 2;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select NAME from test where regexp_like(NAME,'[a]{2}[a-z]*[s]$');
```

Comment: This only selects values that end with `aas`, just like `...where name like '%aas'` would

Comment: Many Thanks. it was searching "aas" together. Now i have corrected it.