# Return maximum occurring character in an input string though Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Say if I have fruit names like Papaya,Orange,etc row by row...

How will I find the maximum occuring character in each string.
For Papaya it will be 'a' as it was repeated 3 times
For Orange it will be all the characters as for each character it was repeated one time only
I need to solve the above query using Oracle SQL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the number of occurrences of a character in an Oracle varchar value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169471/how-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-an-oracle-varchar-value)

Comment: Nope..I need to find the maximum occurence of the character. In that question it was beforehand mention to find the total number of characters of a particular character. But in this question I need to find the character which contains the most number of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     fruit (name)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 'Papaya' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 'Orange' FROM DUAL),
```

---

```
  7     temp
  8     AS
  9        (SELECT name, SUBSTR (name, COLUMN_VALUE, 1) letter
 10           FROM fruit
 11                CROSS JOIN
 12                TABLE (
 13                   CAST (
 14                      MULTISET (    SELECT LEVEL
 15                                      FROM DUAL
 16                                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (name))
 17                         AS SYS.odcinumberlist))),
 18     temp2
 19     AS
 20        (  SELECT name,
 21                  letter,
 22                  COUNT (*) cnt,
 23                  RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY COUNT (*) DESC) rnk
 24             FROM temp
 25         GROUP BY name, letter)
 26    SELECT name,
 27           LISTAGG (letter, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY letter) letters,
 28           cnt
 29      FROM temp2
 30     WHERE rnk = 1
 31  GROUP BY name, cnt;

NAME   LETTERS                     CNT
------ -------------------- ----------
Orange O, a, e, g, n, r              1
Papaya a                             3

SQL>
```

- `TEMP` CTE splits names into rows (by each letter)
- `TEMP2` ranks them by count in descending order
- final `select` returns letters that rank the "highest"

Comment: Thanks mate!!Are there any other ways where we can solve this query in different approach?

Comment: You're welcome. As usual, the same problem can be solved in different ways. I suggested the one I find the most appropriate. I can't think of anything better than that.

Answer (score 0):

I have another idea.

When data is as following.

```sql
create table t as 
  select 'Papaya' w from dual union all
  select 'Orange' w from dual union all
  select 'Baby' w from dual union all
  select 'CocaCola' w from dual
```

Get maximum occurrence of alphabet and count as following

```sql
with cte as (
  select w, az.c find, regexp_count(w, az.c, 1, 'i') cnt
  from   t,
         (select chr(rownum + 96) c
          from   dual
          connect by rownum <= 26
         ) az
),
cte2 as (
  select w, max(lpad(cnt, 10, '0') || find) cnt_find
  from   cte
  group by w
)
select w, substr(cnt_find, 11, 999) find, to_number(substr(cnt_find, 1, 10)) cnt
from   cte2
```

Result:

```
| W        | FIND | CNT |
|----------|------|----:|
| Orange   | r    |   1 |
| Papaya   | a    |   3 |
| Baby     | b    |   2 |
| CocaCola | c    |   3 |
```

Because alphabet set is limited to 26 kind, I generated 26 rows to cross join with word table.

```sql
select chr(rownum + 96) c
from   dual
connect by rownum <= 26
```

And used regexp_count to get occurrence count of each alphabet.

```sql
select w, az.c find, regexp_count(w, az.c, 1, 'i') cnt
```

And retrieved maximum occurrence followed by alphabet groupped by word.
(lpad used to fill 10 length for all occurrence to use substr next step)

```sql
select w, max(lpad(cnt, 10, '0') || find) cnt_find
from   cte
group by w
```

And divided maximum of occurrence and alphabet.
(substr is 1 to 10, and 11 to end because all maximum occurrence is 10 length)

```sql
select w, substr(cnt_find, 11, 999) find, to_number(substr(cnt_find, 1, 10)) cnt
from   cte2
```

This link shows how I made this query in detail.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=29516e70a1270c4035d7165832905777

---

Show all winner instead of first winner

```sql
with cte as (
  select w, az.c find, regexp_count(w, az.c, 1, 'i') cnt
  from   t,
         (select chr(rownum + 96) c
          from   dual
          connect by rownum <= 26
         ) az
), rank_t as 
(
  select w, find, cnt,
         rank() over (partition by w order by cnt desc) rank_cnt
  from   cte
)
select w,
       listagg(find, ', ') within group (order by w) find_list,
       max(cnt) max_cnt
from   rank_t
where  rank_cnt = 1
group by w
```

Result:

```
| W        | FIND_LIST        | MAX_CNT |
|----------|------------------|--------:|
| Baby     | b                |       2 |
| CocaCola | c                |       3 |
| Orange   | a, e, g, n, o, r |       1 |
| Papaya   | a                |       3 |
```

Previous version shows only largest one maximum occurrence. So I used rank function to get all maximum occurrence as number 1

```sql
select w, find, cnt,
       rank() over (partition by w order by cnt desc) rank_cnt
from   cte
```

And filtered only number 1 and converted rows to a column with listagg

```sql
select w,
       listagg(find, ', ') within group (order by w) find_list,
       max(cnt) max_cnt
from   rank_t
where  rank_cnt = 1
group by w
```

This second link shows how I made this query in detail.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c0c15ccb9974d0c4fd14a34408f69fb7

Comment: Hey mate...Thanks for the solution. It is also working fine but say when there is a string such as 'orange' and all the characters are unique then the second column is only returning only one character and not all the characters as all the characters has the maximum occurence of 1 value. Then also with the data which you have provided it will work as expected. Thanks again!!!

Comment: @SSaha You right, I appended for 'orange' case.