# Count a letter in string

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

How can i count the number of 'a' in the string 'rajarajeshwari'

I want count of 'a' in that string

Comment: Why do people not google a solution before asking a question here? Question and answer here are a pure duplicate, see: [How to count the number of occurrences of a character in an Oracle varchar value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169471/how-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-an-oracle-varchar-value) Using google, this is the first result of the search "oracle count letters in string"

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this

```
select length('rajarajeshwari') - length(replace('rajarajeshwari','a',null)) 
from dual;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/wzYGGjaF)

or you can also use the REGEXP_COUNT function

```
select REGEXP_COUNT('rajarajeshwari', 'a') from dual;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/97w6BCE5)